# npe with jsf 2.0 and primefaces 5.2 on WAS 8.0

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, ibm-was

The error is as follows on Websphere Application Server 8.0:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.wrap(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:241)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:156)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:192)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:119)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1071)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:909)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1700)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
    at org.apache.el.util.ReflectionUtil.isAssignableFrom(ReflectionUtil.java:308)
    at org.apache.el.util.ReflectionUtil.getMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:257)
```

The page simply finds all objects that have a contactdate between the from and to entered by the user. I am using primefaces to set up the date pickers and jsf repeat to show the result. The same code runs fine on WAS 8.554 liberty server. I am not even sure how to start looking as the stack trace does not point to my code :(. Thank you.

xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>Occupational Wellness Next Contact</h1>
    <h:outputText value="All models"/>
    <br/>
<br/>

    <h:form>
        <p:calendar id="fromDate" binding="#{startDateComponent}" value="#{contactBean.fromDate}" showOn="button" />

        <p:calendar id="toDate" value="#{contactBean.toDate}" showOn="button">
            <f:validator validatorId="dateRangeValidator" />
            <f:attribute name="startDateComponent" value="#{startDateComponent}" />
        </p:calendar>
        <br/>
        <h:message for="toDate" class="error"/>

        <br/><br/>
        <p:commandButton value="Search" id="search" action="#{contactBean.getModelsWithContactDateBetween(fromDate, toDate)}" ajax="false" />
    </h:form>   
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Participant Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Primary Phone
            </th>
            <th>
                Next Contact Date
            </th>
        </tr>
        <ui:repeat var="model" value="#{contactBean.displayModels}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h:outputText value="#{model.participantName}"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <h:outputText value="#{model.primaryPhone}"/>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <h:outputText id="toDate" value="#{model.nextContactDate}">
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
                    </h:outputText>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </ui:repeat>
    </table>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Gas: how exactly did you conclude OP is providing his own? Nothing in the question indicates that, even not the stacktrace.

Comment: I am new to jsf. I don't think I am using my own. I tried the same application on WAS 8.5.5 and it worked without doing any custom admin configuration. I just put the primefaces jar in the lib folder. So I am going to upgrade WAS instead of trying to figure out the shared library stuff on 8.0 !